# Is this C program safe?

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, palindrome

I am concerned about memory leaks in this program. Specifically, the `check_if_pal` procedure increments the `str` pointer to hide the first character. Will this interfere with automatic memory allocation? Would it be safer to use the heap? Do I need to restore `str` before returning?

This is the code:

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int check_if_pal(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char *not;

        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                if (check_if_pal(argv[i])) {
                        not = " not";
                } else {
                        not = "";
                }

                printf("%s is%s a palindrome.\n", argv[i], not);
        }

        return 0;
}

int check_if_pal(char *str) {

        while (strlen(str) > 1) {
                if (str[0] != str[strlen(str) - 1]) {
                        return 0;
                }

                str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
                str++;
        }

        return 1;
};
```

Comment: "automatic memory allocation". What exactly are you referring to there? But no, there's no problem with that increment. It changes a **local** variable and does not affect the caller's pointer value. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Nothing is allocated here so there can't be any memory leaks.

Comment: No memory issues, but it is very inefficient time-wise (quadratic) because it calls `strlen` (which takes time proportional to the size of the string) a number of times proportional to the size of the string. Try to find a way to do it without modifying the input (`int check_if_pal(const char *str)`).

Comment: Instead of `while (strlen(str) > 1)` just use your pointer: `while (*str)`

Comment: No memory leaks, but `check_if_pal(argv[i])` modifies the string pointed to by `argv[i]` so `printf("%s is%s a palindrome.\n", argv[i], not);` won't (always) print the original `argv[i]`.

Comment: @kaylum I mean allocation on the stack, rather than the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this C program safe?

It is quite hard to analyze due to how you manipulate the `str` pointer. Proving a program is memory-safe can be very easy or very hard depending on how the code is written.

For instance, try calling `strlen` only once and keeping `str` constant. That way you will find it is much easier to prove the indexes stay within bounds.

> I am concerned about memory leaks in this program.

There are no memory leaks since there are no allocations.

> Specifically, the check_if_pal procedure increments the str pointer to hide the first character. Will this interfere with automatic memory allocation?

No, it will not.

> Would it be safer to use the heap?

That depends on the environment, the operating system, the compiler, the flags used...

In general, though, the heap may make errors easier to spot (especially while debugging) since the allocations are more defined.

> Do I need to restore str before returning?

No, the pointer is a copy, so you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is allocated here so there can't be any memory leaks.

Even if you had allocations, remember a pointer does not represent an allocation per-se, it points to the memory *that was allocated* and is necessary to eventually `free()` it. If you lose track of the pointer, if you change the pointer, it does not invalidate the allocation.

You're free to change pointers like `str` that are arguments as much as you want, as that only impacts the local scope of that function.